# Replace NaN values by 'INF'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter several rows of my `Pandas dataframe` and replace the NaN values identified by the filter to replace them by an "infinite" value. Basically loc[] filters out the rows where the column nur=0 and where mtbur is null (mtbur and nur are integers). However, I am aware infinite values don't look clean in a dataset. Therefore what can I do to make my query work and what would you suggest me to add that is similar to an "infinite" value?

Here is the piece of code:

```
df.loc[(df.mtbur.isnull()) & (df.nur==0)].fillna(value='INF')
```

Comment: I think it depends on what you plan to do with the table. What's wrong with leaving NANs in? Most analysis steps e.g. mean automatically ignore NANs. I would think leaving as NaNs would still be fine, but if you must substitute with "inf" maybe numpy.inf would be a better substitute than "inf" since "inf" is a string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **`np.inf`**.

```
import numpy as np
m_inf = (df.mtbur.isnull()) & (df.nur==0)
```

Using [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df = df.mask(m_inf,np.inf)
#df = df.where(~m_inf,np.inf)
```

If you want select specific columns:

```
cols = [list_of_your_columns]
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(m_inf,np.inf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by boolean mask with `np.inf` value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'mtbur':[np.nan,5,4,5,np.nan,np.nan],
         'nur':[0,0,9,0,0,3],
         'col':[np.nan] * 6,

})
mask = (df.mtbur.isnull()) & (df.nur==0)
df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].fillna(np.inf)
print (df)
   A  mtbur  nur  col
0  a    inf    0  inf
1  b    5.0    0  NaN
2  c    4.0    9  NaN
3  d    5.0    0  NaN
4  e    inf    0  inf
5  f    NaN    3  NaN
```

For replace only some columns:

```
mask = (df.mtbur.isnull()) & (df.nur==0)
cols = ['mtbur','A']
df.loc[mask, cols] = df.loc[mask, cols].fillna(np.inf)
print (df)
   A  mtbur  nur  col
0  a    inf    0  NaN
1  b    5.0    0  NaN
2  c    4.0    9  NaN
3  d    5.0    0  NaN
4  e    inf    0  NaN
5  f    NaN    3  NaN
```